# POSTGRESQL - Finding specific product when

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've attempted to write a query but I've not managed to get it working correctly.

I'm attempting to retrieve where a specific product has been bought but where it also has been bought with other products. In the case below, I want to find where product A01 has been bought but also when it was bought with other products.

Data (extracted from tables for illustration):

```
Order | Product
123456 | A01
123457 | A01
123457 | B02
123458 | C03
123459 | A01
123459 | C03
```

Query which will return all orders with product A01 without showing other products:

```
SELECT
O.NUMBER
O.DATE
P.NUMBER

FROM
ORDERS O
JOIN PRODUCTS P on P.ID = O.ID

WHERE
P.NUMBER = 'A01'
```

I've tried to create a sub query which brings back just orders of product A01 but I don't know how to place it in the query for it to return all orders containing product A01 as well as any other product ordered with it.

Any help on this would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the database being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciated Juan's including the DDL to create the database on my system. By the time I saw it, I'd already done all the same work, except that I got around the reserved word problem by naming that field *Order1*.

Sadly, I didn't consider that either of the offered queries worked on my system. I used MySQL.

- The first one returned the A01 lines of the two orders on which other products were ordered too. I took Alex's purpose to include seeing all items of all orders that included A01. (Perhaps he wants to tell future customers what other products other customers have ordered with A01, and generate sales that way.)
- The second one returned the three A01 lines.

Maybe Alex wants:

```
select *
from orders
where Order1 in (select Order1
                 from orders
                 where Product = 'A01')
```

It outputs all lines of all orders that include A01. The subquery makes a list of all orders with A01. The first query returns all lines of those orders.

In a big database, you might not want to run two queries, but this is the only way I see to get the result I understood Alex wanted. If that is what he wanted, he would have to run a second query once armed with output from the queries offered, so there's no real gain.

Good discussion. Thanks to all!

Comment: are you coworker of Alex? Because he say db was postgres.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Not a coworker of Alex. You're right: He tagged his question "postgresql". I don't have it. If your query works in PostgresSQL, more power to you! It only shows A01 rows in MySQL, at least as I copied it. Please take no offense.

Comment: dont worry, no offense. For a moment when i read `create the database on my system.` I tought you were working together

Comment: @BaldEagle Thanks! This lead to a head scratching moment (I had to include a join in the sub query) which then lead to it working correctly. The other two methods didn't quite work as you pointed out. I was pretty close the first time when I did my original sub query but you hit the nail on the head. Thanks for your input, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional `SUM` to detect if one `ORDER` group have one ore more `'A01'`

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    ("Order" int, "Product" varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO orders
    ("Order", "Product")
VALUES
    (123456, 'A01'),
    (123457, 'A01'),
    (123457, 'B02'),
    (123458, 'C03'),
    (123459, 'A01'),
    (123459, 'C03')
;

SELECT "Order" 
FROM orders
GROUP BY "Order"
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN "Product" = 'A01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: use `> 1` because this query will return orders where there is only one product `A01`.

Comment: @vkp I see what you mean. But I understand OP want all order when `A01` appear. Not only the orders where `A01`is only one product as was the query he try in first place.

Comment: `I want to find where product A01 has been bought but also when it was bought with other products`..as i understand, this means, the op needs orders when there is `A01` and atleast one other product.

Comment: @vkp I'm after any order that contains A01 by itself and also any order that has A01 along with any other products. Unsure if I was clear in OP.

Comment: @vkp `I want to find where product A01 has been bought but also ...` that `but also` can be read as both order with just `A01` plus  orders with `A01` and another product. So I will keep it this way for now because on OP query suggest that.. OP can clear what is his desire result .

Comment: It's not quite working as it should. Would the fact that I'm using POSTGRES SQL change things?

Comment: Yes was my fault `ORDER` is a reserved word. Try using `"` or replace by `order_id`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ah, the 'Data' was just example data to illustrate things. The data is stored in tables.

Comment: I update my answer with the correct create table on my db. Didnt work for you?

Comment: I don't need to create any tables as the tables already exist with the data being in there. I think I'm confusing things for all now :S

Comment: as I say..  you cant have a field named `order` in postgresql or any other db because that is a reserved word. I show you a small sample to prove my query works. So either you post the error message or post a more complete schema with your table so we can see where may be the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` clause along with `HAVING` like

```
select "order", Product
from data
group by "order"
having count(distinct product) > 1;
```

Comment: this will return orders where there are products other than `A01` too